# Compile individual SCSS files with rollup.js

Tags: sass, rollupjs

I have multiple css files under a directory named `src/assets/scss`. I want to compile the files to similarly named css files under `dist/assets/css`. For example, `src/assets/scss/a.scss` should be compiled to `dist/assets/css/a.css` and `src/assets/scss/b.scss` should be compiled to `dist/assets/css/b.css`.

How can I do this with rollup?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need rollup. Sass already comes with a feature to allow for exactly this. As you may know Sass file which start with an underscore are not individually compiled, e.g. `_functions.scss` or `_mixins.scss` will only be compiled if they are first *imported* into a file *not* starting with an underscore. But if you create a folder called `sass`, all files that are supposed to be compiled will automaticaly compile into individular file inside a folder called `css`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I would like to use a single build tool, instead of separate tools for JS / CSS.

Comment: @JoyceBabu, any Sass compiler will do this.